# Where is the source code of /usr/bin/[‽

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils

This question might be well asked, but with the poor googlability, I've failed to find similar question in Stack Overflow. I'm using Ubuntu, but not stuck to it, so any answers for other distributions are welcome.

Comment: The title for your question appears to stop after the [; it would help to know the full item you are referring to.

Comment: @CoveGeek: the utility is literally called `[` (open bracket).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coreutils` package, `src/lbracket.c` and `src/test.c`.

Comment: Thanks, man. I've checked the `coreutils` before asking this, but only checked `[.c` exists :) By the way, why it's implemented like this and not as a symlink?!

Comment: Not sure; I suppose it's to bind the difference in behaviour to the executable itself, rather than the name of the file (so that even if you rename it, it still carries the original behaviour). But I can only guess.

Comment: As a hardlink, it will run a little faster than as a symlink.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Well, separate executable, not hardlink, but same reasoning would apply. Yes, that might be a good explanation.